# how to get value of contentBytes from microsoft graph sdk data response in php

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

My code is

```
$expand="microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item";
            $requestUrl = '/me/messages/'.$message->getId().'/attachments/?$expand=  '.$expand;
            $docDatas = $userClient->createCollectionRequest('GET', $requestUrl)
                                    ->setReturnType(Model\Message::class)
                                    ->setPageSize(1)
                                      ->getPage();
```

And want to get the outlook email attachment

Please help my

we get responses like this

```
Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message Object
(
    [_propDict:protected] => Array
        (
            [@odata.type] => #microsoft.graph.fileAttachment
            [@odata.mediaContentType] => application/pdf
            [id] => AAMkADE2M2FjZjMyLTY2YjAtNDQwZi1hMzc3LTI2MjYwNmQ0NTJhYwBGAAAAAAB13byROi0bTImrZtPU6w6LBwAIBVrWv6bqRZ6zXuSjdaiOAAAAAAEMAAAIBVrWv6bqRZ6zXuSjdaiOAAUI9pGdAAABEgAQABzAnt_evzNMiFTD_ANAZno=
            [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2022-06-28T05:54:14Z
            [name] => test.pdf
            [contentType] => application/pdf
            [size] => 66087
            [isInline] => 
            [contentId] => 6D16B02E2C840A419B9F0FEBD656E618@namprd13.prod.outlook.com
            [contentLocation] => 
            [contentBytes] => JVBERi0xLjQKJe...
        )

)
```

[image: See Attachment]

***I want to get value contentBytes but how?***
Again get error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFIry.png)

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. What is the request you use? Is the image you posted the print_r result from the object you received? Could you share the link to the Microsoft library you use (library that contains: Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message)

Comment: we use this :-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: is this the library you use: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php?
I've updated the answer according to your code updates

Comment: have you managed to resolve it? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either extend `Message` with a `CustomMessage` class and than have a specific getter for that property if you'll use it extensively.
My assumption was that you use [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) library.

Other, simpler solution would be to just:

```
$expand="microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item";
$requestUrl = '/me/messages/'.$message->getId().'/attachments/?$expand=  '.$expand;
$docDatas = $userClient->createCollectionRequest('GET', $requestUrl)
                       ->setReturnType(Model\Message::class)
                       ->setPageSize(1)
                       ->getPage();

$properties = $docDatas->getProperties();
$contentBytes = $properties["contentBytes"];
```

Message extends `OutlookMessage` which extends `Microsoft\Graph\Model\Entity`. You can find `getProperties` method in that class.

Comment: Hello @boroboris thanks for your answer but we get blank

Answer (score 0):

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model\Attachment;

$filename = 'my_file.jpg';
$filepath = '/path/to/file/my_file.jpg';
$filetype = mime_content_type($filepath);
$stream = Stream(fopen($filepath, 'r+'));

$file_attachement = new FileAttachment();
$file_attachement->setODataType('#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment');
$file_attachement->setName($filename);
$file_attachement->setContentType($filetype);
$file_attachement->setContentBytes(base64_encode($stream));

$message = new Message();
$message->setAttachments(array($file_attachement));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding some content to your answer explaining what you are doing or how your code is solving the problem besides a code snippet.